# listing all members of an active directory group

Tags: c#, active-directory, clr

I'm having trouble retrieving the members of a certain group in active directory. The code I'm using is the following:

```
[Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlFunction(FillRowMethodName = "fillRow")]
public static IEnumerable getNTGroupMembers(string groupName)
    {
        SearchResult result;
        DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher();
        search.Filter = String.Format("(cn={0})", groupName);
        search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("member");
        result = search.FindOne();

        ArrayList userNames = new ArrayList();
        if (result != null)
        {
            for (int counter = 0; counter < result.Properties["member"].Count; counter++)
            {
                object user = (object)result.Properties["member"][counter];
                userNames.Add(user);
            }
        }
        return userNames;
    }
```

but it returns me a list of the following:

> CN=X,OU=x,OU=X,OU=X,OU=X,DC=X,DC=X,DC=X

Does anyone know how I can return the member's username. I've tried getting different properties, but I haven't been able to get this to work.

This is part of a CLR  function that I'm creating for SQL Server 2005.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well i managed to do it. It still has some problems, for some reason for some AD groups it doesn't return some of its members.
If anyone knows a better way to do this please tell me!

```
[Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlFunction(FillRowMethodName = "fillRow")]
public static IEnumerable getNTGroupMembers(string groupName)
{
    SearchResult result;
    DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher();
    search.Filter = String.Format("(cn={0})", groupName);
    search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("member");
    result = search.FindOne();
    ArrayList userNames = new ArrayList();
    if (result != null)
    {
        for (int counter = 0; counter < result.Properties["member"].Count; counter++)
        {
            string st = (string) result.Properties["member"][counter];
            DirectoryEntry gpMemberEntry = new DirectoryEntry(("LDAP://" + st));
            if (!(gpMemberEntry == null))
            {
                PropertyCollection userProps = gpMemberEntry.Properties;
                object objUser = userProps["sAMAccountname"].Value;
                userNames.Add(objUser);
            }
        }
    }
    return userNames;
}
private static void fillRow(Object obj, out string user)
{
    object row = (object)obj;
    user = (string)row;
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to modify the above solution to get all users, including the ones that are members of the group but located within a separate domain?  I have a group that returns the list of users associated with my group that I am querying.  However, when I get back the ArrayList of users, all of the users that are not part of the same domain as the group have a Null value in the Value property of the sAMAccountname object.